# How to call php method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I already doing research in here.
Many people say ajax is better.
But I want to ask something first because I never use ajax.

I want to delete some row in database if I push yes on the `windows.confirm using javascipt`.

My `HTML button`

```
<button onclick="deleteFunction()">Del</button>
```

My `Javascript function`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function deleteColumn(id)
  {
    if (confirm("Are you want to delete?") === true) {
      // Do delete method in PHP
    } else {
      // Cancel delete
    }
  }
</script>
```

My `delete` method in `Storage class`

```
class Storage
{
  public function delete($condition)
  {
    // Delete from database with condition
  }
}
```

Do I must use `ajax` to call `PHP method`?

Comment: no, if you don't want to use an ajax then normal submission would do

Comment: What kevin said, and also, why call `deleteFunction()` when you on have `deleteColumn()` defined?

Comment: For your `//Do delete method in PHP`, you must redirect to a PHP file (or not redirect, make another request that calls a file, eg. ajax) that actually does the delete.

Comment: like `<?php delete() ?>` ?
@Darren hmm.. Just want to seperate function for database. Storage class job is setting something in database.

Comment: upon submission, get the id, instantiate the object, feed it into the method use `mysqli_*` or pdo functions and execute the proper delete statement. anyway are you using a php framework? or you just create your own class?

Comment: @kevinabelita I create my own class. I want to call Storage class method because it is his job to do something in database.

Comment: then start [coding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) your method: `delete($id)`, my comment above was just the basic idea, this is too broad anyway

Comment: Okay2, I already found something from you guys. I'll begin my research again. Thanks2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you basic flow:

```
<!-- the form sample -->
<form method="POST" action="your_php.php" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you want to delete?');">
    ID: <input type="text" name="id" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

In PHP:

```
<?php

class Storage
{
    public function delete($id)
    {
        // should be better if this is another class
        $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'your_db_username', 'db_password', 'database_name');
        $stmt = $connection->prepare('DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $storage = new Storage();
    $storage->delete($id);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important to have two concepts clear, execution in server side and execution in client side.

**Server side**, like php, the code is interpreted in the web server.

**Client side**, like javascript, the code is interpreted in the browser of the user.

AJAX is really good to make the two sides work "together" without disturbing the user experience.

Using AJAX in this case isn't a must. AJAX is useful when you want to make an action without reloading all your site. If what you want to do is that, try using some jQuery function, like:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "yourPHPfunction.php",
   data: {
     row: 123
   }
   }).done(function() {
       alert("The row was deleted.")
});
```

in your js delete() function.

If you don't want to use AJAX, make a GET or POST request (via js) to the PHP file where you had coded the delete function.

It will be good if you take a look to jQuery API documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).
But before, to have a background about AJAX, it's good to read [that](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/a-quick-guide-to-understanding-ajax).

Comment: I can't use any library because I'm studying.

Comment: In this case, it will be useful this article: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript--net-4855

Comment: Be aware that, in the raw way, you will have tons of cross-browser problems. Probably it will work fine in one but not in the other. And when uyou finally fix it it will work fin in the other but not in the firs one ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would answer with a simple phrase :

**Look this video :** [How PHP Works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PemsuAfc7Jw)

You will understand yourself, why what you are asking is not possible without AJAX.

Enjoy the video, and see you :)

I hope this answer will help you to figure out why you cannot do what you want to, without using AJAX or similar ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will learn from it.

Comment: Don't take it like an agression, i just hope that you will understand that PHP is server-side evaluated, you cannot run it into the client browser ... Keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

The php code need the php interpreter to run. 
The browser cannot find the php interpreter to run your code in the javascript. So you must call a php server to help you.It will run your code and return your result.Using ajax is a better idea!